# c programming: cant store contents of file into array of structs

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I am trying relatively new to programming and have been asked as part of an assignment to create a program that opens a file and reads the data into an array of structs by dynamically creating sufficient memory for each entry read from the file. The contents are in a text file and displayed as follows:
• Name: John Smith
• Vaccine vendor: Pfizer
• Vaccination date: 02/08/2021
• Date of birth: 06/01/1990
• Underlying condition: None
• Student/Staff ID: 556679

• Name: Mary Jones
• Vaccine vendor: None
• Vaccination date: None
• Date of birth: 09/10/1988
• Underlying condition: Asthma
• Student/Staff ID: 556677

I haven't much experience with structs or dynamic memory allocation. I have tried the below program but cannot seem to get this to work. Any advice is appreciated.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void load_data();


typedef struct {
    char* name;
    char* vaccinevendor;
    char* vaccinationdate;
    char* dob;
    char* underlyingcond;
    int* id;
}  Record;

Record array[15];

int main(void)
{
    load_data();

    return 0;
}

void load_data()
{

    long filelen;

    FILE* Ptr = (char*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char)); /*file pointer*/

    if ((Ptr = fopen("records.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("File does not exist\n");
    }
    else {
        Ptr = fopen("records.txt", "w");
        if (Ptr != NULL)
            printf("records.txt file has now been created.\n");
        else {
            printf("Unable to create file!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        fgets(array, 1000, Ptr);
    }
    fclose(Ptr); /*close stream*/

}
```

Comment: `FILE* Ptr = (char*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));` !!! That is very wrong.  You should call `fopen` to get a FILE *

Comment: The initial allocation for `Ptr` is pointless, since you throw away the value in the next line.  But you can get a much better error message with `if ((Ptr = fopen("records.txt", "r")) == NULL) { perror("records.txt");}`

Comment: But `fopen("records.txt", "r")` followed by `fopen("records.txt", "w")` is problematic.  The open for writing truncates (discards) all of the data in the file.  You should not try to read and write from the same file.

Comment: there is no need to fopen w if you are just reading from a file. After the first fopen r, you can directly use the file for read.